# How to update multiple columns of dynamo db using aws iot rules engine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, rules, rule-engine, aws-iot

I have set of data: `id`, `name`, `height` and `weight`.

I am sending this data to aws iot in json format. From there I need to update the respective columns in a dynamo db hence I have created 3 rules to update `name`, `height` and weight keeping `id` as partition key.

But when I send the message only one column is getting updated. If I disable any 2 rules then the remaining rule works fine. Therefore every time I update, columns are getting overwritten.

How can I update all three columns from the incoming message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: You can't do this with the IoT gateway rules themselves. You can only store data in a single column through the rules (apart from the hash and sort key).

A way around this is to make a lambda rule which calls for example a python script which then takes the message and stores it in the table. See also [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42540358/220986).

Answer (score 3):

Another answer: in your rule, use instead the "**dynamoDBv2**" action -- which "allows you to write all or part of an MQTT message to a DynamoDB table. Each attribute in the payload is written to a separate column in the DynamoDB database ..."

dynamoDBv2 action: writes each attribute in the payload to a separate column in the DynamoDB database.

Comment: More infomation about this can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/dynamodb-v2-rule.html